# Imprimir información de un JSON a HTML usando JavaScript y API REST

Tags: javascript, html, json, scrap

He estado intentando recoger informacion usando `XMLHttpRequest`, para coger un `JSON` de una API Rest, imprime en consola el `JSON` pero no logro sacar esa info por `HTML` en mi web, necesito un contador de descargas de un programa.

**Ej:** Descargas: ***x***

Pero por alguna razon no puedo sacar la información en la web...
Uso Apache2/VSCode/Chrome/XAMPP, por si ayuda, aquí está el código:

**JSON**

```
{
    "id": "78993",
    "title": "PermaDeathCore",
    "tag": "Permadeath HardCore Mode",
    "current_version": "PDC",
    "author": {
        "id": "973464",
        "username": "vo1d_dev"
    },
    "premium": {
        "price": "0.00",
        "currency": ""
    },
    "stats": {
        "downloads": "12",
        "updates": "0",
        "reviews": "0",
        "rating": "0"
    }
}
```

```js
function JSONRequest(){
    
    let XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.spigotmc.org/simple/0.1/index.php?action=getResource&id=78993');
    request.send();
    request.onload = () => {
    let JSONFile = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    let downloads = JSON.parse(JSONFile.stats.downloads);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = downloads;
    }
}

JSONRequest();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="/src/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="JSONRequest()">
        <strong>Downloads: <span id="output"></span></strong>
    </body>
    <script src="/src/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there! You are in the Spanish version. Please translate it or consider to move it to Stackoverflow.com (English version) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

primero que todo... ¿Estás completamente seguro de que recibes un `JSON` y lo muestras por consola?

Recuerda que la sentencia `require` hace parte de los modulos de `nodejs` y no de `javascript puro`, es decir que en javascript puro no existe.

De todas maneras hay algo que me parece extraño... y es esta parte de aqui:

```
let XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Porque intentas requerir un modulo?, hay que entender algo, `XMLHttpRequest` es nativo de `javascript`, por lo cual no requieres de instalar ni requerir modulos externos para obtener un `XMLHttpRequest`, mira este ejemplo sin usar `require`:

```js
const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(ajax);
```

Como vemos **existe nativamente** sin importar ningun modulo o instalar alguno, de todas maneras aunque intentaras usar la version del modulo `XMLHttpRequest` que tienes, estas importandola en una parte erronea.

**Los modulos e importaciones de recursos externos... NUNCA se importan después del inicio del documento.**

Si intentas importarlos en una parte distinta definitivamente te va a dar errores. Por ejemplo:

**MAL:**

```
//Inicio del documento

//Inicio del codigo
function JSONRequest(){
                         //Mal uso de require, fallara.
    let XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

}
```

**BIEN:**

```
//Inicio del documento
let XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest; 

//Inicio del codigo
function JSONRequest(){
    ...
}
```

Ahora bien, respecto a la pregunta original del como puedes mostrar esta data en tu elemento, primero hare la misma pregunta del inicio...

**¿Estas seguro de que recibes un JSON como respuesta?**

Existe un problema, un problema que no puedes resolver tu, ni yo ni ninguno de nosotros, y es que tienes problemas de **origenes cruzados** o como se le dice en ingles **Cross-Origins**.

Las **CORS** o cabeceras de origenes cruzados son una medida de seguridad tomada por los recursos de las paginas web las cuales le indican a la pagina aquellos usuarios o dominios los cuales podran acceder o no a los recursos, de esta manera se previene que cualquier persona intente acceder a un recurso no autorizado solamente haciendo uso de peticiones `HTTP`.

Desactivar las `CORS` es absurdamente sencillo, pero el inconveniente es no tener nosotros el acceso a ese archivo para añadir esa cabecera de acceso... en pocas palabras:

- Si no eres dueño del recurso y no añades esa cabecera (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) al archivo no vas a poder acceder a el de ninguna manera hagas lo que hagas.

Aun hay opciones... como buscar otras `APIS` que tengan acceso publico (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`) o en caso de que seas el propietario de la `API`, simplemente añadir esta cabecera en el documento del lado del servidor.

Pero por el momento, a no ser de que la `API` te de acceso especial (por ejemplo una `API KEY` que puedas enviar junto con la peticion), no hay manera de desactivar esas `CORS` del lado del servidor.

El motivo de mi pregunta es porque, aunque yo pueda abrir directamente el archivo y ver el `JSON` desde aquí:

[enlace API](https://api.spigotmc.org/simple/0.1/index.php?action=getResource&id=78993)

Esto no es lo mismo que tratar de obtener esta información en un sitio web diferente (petición `HTTP` o `XHTTP` hacia ese archivo).

La razon por la que todos podemos ver el `JSON` si vamos directamente a ese link, es porque esa `URL` se encuentra en el mismo dominio (`hoisted by the same site`).

Mientras que nuestro sitio se encuentra obviamente en un dominio diferente (`not hoisted by the same site`), asi que cuando intentamos obtener esta información en tu archivo dara problemas de `origenes cruzados`, `CORS`.

Soluciones posibles:

- Buscar otra `API` pero que tenga acceso publico.
- Si eres propietario de la `API` añadir esta cabecera para tu dominio o hacer de ese archivo un recurso publico.

He confirmado que se trata de `CORS`, puesto que al intentar hacer `fetch` en vez de `XMLHttpRequest` también se obtiene el mismo problema (`CORS`):

```js
fetch("https://api.spigotmc.org/simple/0.1/index.php?action=getResource&id=78993")
.then(res =>{
  res.json();
})
.then(r =>{
  console.log(r);
})
.catch(e =>{
  console.error(e);
})
```

Se que no se ve que sea explicitamente las `CORS`, pero cuando intentamos esto desde otra cosa que no sea este snippet, aparece la parte del error de `CORS`.

De todas maneras, aunque nosotros no podamos solucionar directamente este error de `CORS`, he decidido organizar y corregir un poco tu codigo en lo posible, por si de algo te ayuda:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

  function JSONRequest(){
    
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      
      request.onload = () => {
        let JSONFile = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        let downloads = JSONFile.stats.downloads;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = downloads;
      }
      
      request.onerror = e =>{
        console.error(e);
      }
      
      request.open('GET', 'https://api.spigotmc.org/simple/0.1/index.php?action=getResource&id=78993');
      request.send();
      
  }

  JSONRequest();

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <strong>Downloads: <span id="output"></span></strong>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: De hecho si vas al enlace del JSON en el apartado Cabeceras podras ver que efectivamente falta la cabecera Access-Control-Allow-Origin.